# ShoutCAST Streaming with JPlayer Not Working (No Error)

Tags: audio, streaming, jplayer, shoutcast

I've got a ShoutCAST stream and decided to give JPlayer a try. I've researched as much as I can on my on, but still can not seem to get it to work and I am not getting any error messages. My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "http://67.205.95.146:8068/;stream/1"
        }).jPlayer("play");
    },


    swfPath: "http://www.fightfansradio.com/wp-content/themes/FFR2/js/Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "mp3", 
    wmode: "window"
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

- I have an absolute path the SWF file
- I double checked my encoding and it is indeed MP3
- Again, I'm not getting any error messages
- The player doesn't seem to work at all as if it can't find the stream

I feel like I did quite a bit of research trying to solve this issue myself, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've verified that your stream is MP3, and you don't have any oddball sample rates or anything.  Can you fire up your browser tools to further debug the issue?  Verify that a connection to SHOUTcast is being made.  Wireshark might also be helpful.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in Firebug and you can verify the stream is live by going to the link (http://67.205.95.146:8068/). This would be less frustrating if I would at least get an error to address.

Answer (score 0):

I used this below Coding for Live streaming, it plays on in the primcast.com website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.primcast.com/jwplayer/swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="player_preview" style="float:left;">
    This text will be replaced. Streaming solutions by  
    <a href="http://www.primcast.com">Primcast - Shoutcast hosting, Flash Streaming</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var so = new SWFObject('http://www.primcast.com/jwplayer/mediaplayer.swf','mpl',560,20,'9'); 
    so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always'); 
    so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true'); 
    so.addParam('flashvars','&autostart=true&duration=-1&file=http://93.91.197.214:1234/;stream.nsv'); 
    so.write('player_preview') 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This reply might be late. If you are trying to play the audio in Android, remove
.jPlayer("play"). For some reason Android does not like auto-play.